# Action Listener / action performed order

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

This question already has an answer here:

I want to subscribe to two objects/classes at the same action (addActionListener). 
The notifications will be done with an order? 
Maybe the same order of addActionListener? 
Or the related action will have a non-preordained sequence?

For example, I made two addActionListener for an Ok button, inside a swing form. After Ok was pushed, I want to manage some fields, inside the form, as I need and then notify also the controller.
Does exist a better method to do this?

I've made this simple test that I attach.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class testbutton {
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ButtonController bController = new ButtonController();
                    Button frame = new Button(bController);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }   
}


/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
class Button extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 
    public Button(ButtonController b) {

        // b is the ButtonController object 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 376, 201);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JButton btnButton1 = new JButton("New button");

        // It is important the order of addActionListener?

        // subscibe ButtonController
        btnButton1.addActionListener(b);

        //I am listen (observe) myself (this)
        btnButton1.addActionListener(this); 

        contentPane.add(btnButton1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    // actionPerformed receive the notification e is the event  
    // related to notify. What's happened to the notifier.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside myself");

    }       
}
```

And this the Controller

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ButtonController implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Waiting notification.
        // The "Button Controller" need to be instantiated before 
        //the object who do the addActionListener.
        // This instance will be passed to addActionListener
        System.out.println("Inside controller");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the code in the same ActionListener. The order a listener is invoked is not guaranteed by the Java language specs.

Comment: Woha.I suggest to first focus on learning the basics of good OOP and swing ui things. To call your class Button but to extend jframe... That is close to crazy.

Comment: @GhostCat. Of course. My first intent  isn't simply to build a java program, but learn OOP,  Java and swing. I'm a beginner, this is why  I think my question is trivial,  so I asking suggestions.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the order that the listeners are notified as the order is undefined (by the documentation), if you need chained results, where order matters, use a single listener which calls the functionality you need in the order you need

Comment: Just to upgrade. As I said, I'm a Java beginner, and I'm drowned "on a glass of water". I'm lost myself on swing's components.
What I needed was a JDialog, already implemented, but with missing return, so I'm able to intercept OK button, in JDialog, elaborate my input and return a object. Not so easy the first time.